# ajax to php $variable

Tags: php, ajax

I try to pass this value to my php code, but I do not know how to do it. post method does not work. (I do not know why).

```
<script>
    var val = localStorage.getItem('sumalist');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {value: val},
        success: function () {
            console.log(val);
        }
    });
</script>
```

and in my php code, value is not set.

```
if (isset($_POST["value"])) {
    echo "Yes, value is set";
    $value = $_POST["value"];
}else{
    echo "N0, value is not set";

}
```

PS: My php code is in the same file in js code.

Comment: How do you run your javascript code? Did you get any errors?

Comment: My code js in the same file in php code - index.php || no, my console only shows the value I want to pass to php

Comment: Given the code and the fact that `index.php` is returning a HTML document with that script tag included, you won't notice whether the value is set or not. The return value of your ajax request is never used... Please specify what you wan't to achieve after sending the ajax request.

Comment: My `var val = localStorage.getItem('sumalist');` returns a float. I would like this value send to sql query.:

Comment: `$value = $_POST["value"];

                    if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO zamowienia VALUES ('$value')")) ...`

Answer (score 2):

Check if this works

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $value = (isset($_POST["value"])) ?  $_POST["value"] : NULL;
    $return = ($value != NULL) ? "Yes, value is: ".$value : "N0, value is not set";
    echo $return;
    exit;
}
?>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var val = 'value sent';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {value: val},
        success: function (ret) {
            console.log(ret);
        }
    });
</script>
Open console for result
```

Comment: why not just `print_r($_POST); exit;`?

Comment: it would be even better but he wants to have this message with set/not set

Comment: Yes true that, but if he/she is knowing what he/she is doing there wouldn't be such a question :)

Comment: `N0, value is not set`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the response in callback success function, use this:

```
success: function (ret) {
    console.log(ret); //Prints 'Yes, value is set' in browser console
}
```

Comment: My console show my all html code in my file, and this solution does not work either.

Comment: It returns the entire HTML code because your PHP code and the HTML data are in the same file (HTML tags are output by server after PHP code is processed by PHP core). Create a different file called 'script.php', put the PHP code in there, modify the target from Ajax request to 'script.php' and it should work.

Comment: `data: {'value': val}` and `data: {value: val}` are absolutely equal, even you have defined `var value`, JavaScript do not allow variables as property in this way of Object defining.

Answer (score 0):

Please use console if you're using chrome then open console and try debugging, 
And first you run that ajax function in jquery ready function like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){ $.ajax( replaced for ajax function ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your browser you have Developer Tools - press F12 to open, go to Network tab (FireFox, Chrome, IE - all the same), then reload your page and you will see the line for your AJAX call (if it is performed on load, or trigger your call if this is not the case), select it and right hand you'll see a extra frame where you can see all the details of your request, including request params, headers, response headers, the actual response and many other.

That's the best solution to check your AJAX request without asking uncompleted questions and seeking for the answers in case someone can assemble your full case in his mind.

Believe me - this is the best solution for you and not only for this case!

Of course your JS should be performed when DOM is ready so you have to wrap it in

```
${function() {
  // your code here 
});
```

in case you want to be executed on load.